# Is there a way to list what files were changed with each commit in svn?

Tags: svn

For the last, say, 20 commits I want to see what files were modified in each commit.

I'd want the output to look basically like `svn log`'s but with a list of files modified by each individual commit.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd want the output to look basically like svn log's but with a list of files modified by each individual commit

```
$ svn log -v $REPO
```

That will look like Subversion's log output and show you a list of files modified by each individual commit.